# Which File-system to install on external device to store files from both Win10 and Mac?

Tags: windows-10, mac, filesystems

I have a 4 TB USB3 external storage device from WD. I need to store and read files on this device from BOTH Windows 10 x64 and from Mac Catalina. Which is the best FILE-SYSTEM to format this device for this purpose?

Comment: The links under "This question already has answers here:" are **OUTDATED** !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the following:

exFAT or FAT32

Both will work.

Good luck!

Comment: *Why* should they use one of these? What benefits are there? What downsides? You might want to read [How do I write a good answer?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Sometimes, when opening the exFAT device from Windows10, I get a message from Windows that there are problems on the device and that I should fix them. How can I check for problems on an exFAT device and repair them?

Comment: @Mokubai Why waste more words answering questions the OP disn't ask about? exFAT and FAT32 are widely available and work on Macs and Windows.  OP didn't ask for a lecture about downsides/benefits. Both your link and disdain aren't appreciated either. (Insert link here on how to behave)

Comment: Surely then you could have saved even more words by simply voting to close as one of the many duplicates we have on this exact subject https://superuser.com/search?q=windows+mac+external+filesystem+is%3Aq No disdain here, just an desire for high quality answers that say *why* rather than just *"do that because I say so"*. If offence was taken then I apologise as it was not intended, I'm sure that help page was written better in the past...